# Why Limit exceed for tweet using twitter4j

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I am using twitter4j for post tweet . I post one tweet each 30 minute after post 2-3 tweet i got this error.

```
403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
message - Status is a duplicate.
code - 187

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=2fc5b7cb or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0ea287d2
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[2fc5b7cb-0ea287d2], statusCode=403, message=Status is a duplicate., code=187, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.4}
    at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:164)
```

Any one help me how can i post tweet using twitter4j .How much time difference between 2 tweet post i will take.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot publish 2 times the exact same tweet. Twitter will prevent that.
If you post tweets with a different message, you should not receive this error.

Comment: I post same tweet after 2 days or not

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Don't post the EXACT same tweet within a close period of time to ensure that you won't encounter this problem. Twitter will reject the operation otherwise.